# WPF thread safety and communication between pages

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, thread-safety

I am new to C# and .Net and I have some doubts regarding WPF thread safety and how different WPF pages should communicate with each other. My main project would have a class called `MainWindow.cs` with `MainWndow.xaml`. In addition, I will have two pages called  `Page1.cs` with `Page1.xaml` and `Page2.cs` with `Page2.xaml`. Reading the documentation, I know that each WPF page has its own thread and all the controls of WPF should only be accessed through the same thread , in case I have  one background thread in the same page, I can access the controls of WPF in background thread through following example

```
controlName.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>updateControl())
```

My question is if the same operation, I want to do from `Page1.cs` class by changing for example
the textbox either on  `MainWndow.xaml` or `Page2.xaml`. How can be done these operations safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reading the documentation, I know that each WPF page has its own thread

This is incorrect, or at least misleading. Each WPF control has a thread that owns said control, and all access has to be done from this thread. But in the majority of cases, it is the same thread that owns all controls. So there is no concern about thread safety.

It is possible to have multiple windows that are owned by different UI threads, but this is rarely recommended just because all the issues with thread safety and synchronization.

So, unless you are doing something uncommon, you should only need to care if you are running things on the single UI thread, or a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and I would also suggest taking a look at MVVM Pattern if you are going to do some projects with WPF